# How to fix product drop down in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am facing this problem after update of plugins. How can i solve this?[image: Size Select Option]

Comment: Which WooCommerce update you did?

Comment: the new woocommerce version is 3.70

Comment: Are there any JavaScript errors in the console?